# Puppet client not connection to master - SSL connect Error

Tags: linux, ssl-certificate, puppet, puppetmaster

I installed the puppet master and agent on the same machine. When the client is started, I got the following error message.

```
puppet agent --server=agent.com --no-daemonize --debug



err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed.  This is often because the time is out of sync on the server or client
```

Comment: Obvious question: is the time in sync?

Comment: master and client are both in same machine. So time should be synced, I guess.

Comment: Doh, completely misread :) Can you do an x509 dump of the server cert (opssl x509 -noout -text /path/to/server.crt) and add that to your post. Next guess is that the DN in the cert doesn't match the hostname of the machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making an entry in /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost puppet
```

remove the `--server` argument to the puppet agent command.

Answer (score 10):

Find out the [FQDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fqdn) of your puppetmaster by issuing:

```
# openssl x509 -noout -subject -in /var/lib/puppet/ssl/ca/ca_crt.pem
subject= /CN=Puppet CA: host.domain.com
```

Compare with the output (if any) of:

```
# puppet cert list --all
```

Add an entry to your `/etc/hosts` file pointing the IP listening in the `puppetmaster` port (`8140`):

```
192.168.124.2  host.domain.com host
```

To find out which IP to use, you need to know the process listening, which is different if this is a standalone `puppetmaster` or an `apache`+`passenger` installation. You can use:

```
netstat -an | grep 8140.*LISTEN
```

Check your `/etc/puppet/puppet.conf` file, specifically the `server=` entry, which should be pointing to the FQDN described above.

Don't use `localhost`, unless you don't want this `puppetmaster` to be found.

Before starting the `pupppet agent`, issue:

```
# puppet agent --test --waitforcet 2
```

which instructs the agent to send a CSR to the puppetmaster CA and wait for it to be signed.

Check using

```
# puppet cert --list
```

The pending to sign CSR. Sign it:

```
# puppet cert sign host.domain.com
```

Watch puppet agent receive a compiled catalog and apply it. After that, you are ready to start the agent and add it to the startup scripts.

Comment: @UdaraS.SLiyanage Please mark the answer as accepted for future reference

Comment: Upvoted you.  Your steps were much more thorough.

Answer (score 0):

I found that having the following set in `/etc/puppet/puppet.conf` to solve a case where regenerating certs "by the book" still produced the situation described in the Q:

```
[master]
certname=masterhost.domain.com

[agent]
certname=agenthost.domain.com
```

(where `masterhost.domain.com` is the FQDN of the puppetmaster and `agenthost.domain.com` the same for the agent)

IMO this is rather clear way of ensuring that puppet knows which name is for the master and which is for the agent in the case of having both running on the same host, especially as having just set `server=masterhost.domain.com` didn't seem to be enough to avoid conflicts.

I didn't find the proposed solution of adding the DN of the puppetmaster in `/etc/hosts` (I had it as an DNS alias already) so I can't say if that would have helped in my case.